# Export MD5 encrypted password into magento

Tags: magento, md5

I have a list of MD5 encrypted customer's password from old website now i am move to magento. How do i import list of md5 encrypted passwords of users into magento.

Comment: I assume you want to import more than just their password hashes?

Comment: You can simply import the MD5 user password in Magento without any modification and they will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to do this:

Go to Magento admin->System->Import/Export->Dataflow profiles. (NOT to Magento admin->System->Import/Export->Import!)

Then, select profile: Import Customers (or create if it not exists).

I set the Store value in Profile information box to 'Default store view'. Then, upload Your csv, and run the profile.

It worked for me and goes every value into magento database correctly - shipping and billing addresses too.

Here is my CSV header:

```
id  website firstname   lastname    email   password_hash   billing_firstname   billing_lastname    billing_company billing_postcode    billing_city    billing_street1 billing_telephone   billing_country billing_region  shipping_firstname  shipping_lastname   shipping_company    shipping_postcode   shipping_city   shipping_street1    shipping_telephone  shipping_country    shipping_region is_subscribed   group   group_id    dob
```